# Help with a small script to start something after network comes back on

Tags: pi-3

I have a script that starts a software when the pi boots up. Works hundred percent as it should. I've setup another script to change the software to another state when the network goes down, but I have no idea how to change it back to its original state when the network comes back online.

On a side note, I've only managed the other stuff due to my awesome Google powers, but they have failed me this time.

Any help will be awesome

Comment: This is the main script controlling everything:
#!/bin/bash

# Ping to see if it works
SERVER=192.168.1.195

# Only send two pings, sending output to /dev/null
ping -c2 ${SERVER} > /dev/null

# If the return code from ping ($?) is not 0 (meaning there was an error)
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    # Load Offline Script
   sh ./streamdown.sh
    echo "Stream is Down"
else
sh ./streamup.sh
echo "Stream is Up"

fi

Comment: The then part works, but if I unplug my network cable nothing happens. If I plug it back in the then part starts working again. ANy help

Answer (score 1):

You could add :

```
post-up /home/pi/your-script.sh
```

to your **/etc/network/interfaces** file.
This will run your script after your network interfaces come up.

Comment: Thank you very much. But would that run it as soon as the network comes up the first time after boot or after boot. Like I said the script does work after boot, it's after it cannot ping,  then ping comes back that I want it to run the original script.

Comment: That would work at boot and (I believe) other times when your network interface (goes down and) comes up again.